# Export an html table with an image to a spreadsheet using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Need to export an html table with an image to a spreadsheet using Jquery. I used CSV for export, but image is not exported

```
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
 $("#tbContainer").tableToCSV();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSV format can not contain images. However it could contain URLs pointing to the images. You can then load them with a macro:

```
For Each cel In Selection
    cel.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(cel.Value).Select
Next cel
```